# Get Which Server Local TeamSpeak 3 Client is Connected To

Tags: c#, .net, client

Is there any way to check if the TeamSpeak 3 client on the same computer is connected to a specific server? (same computer as the app that does this check)

Alternatively, is there any way to check a TeamSpeak 3 server's client list (users connected to the server) that doesn't include using the steam query login credentials (I know the steam query port, but not login credentials)?

I'd like to do this in a C# .NET desktop application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Though this might coming late to your question, but here's my answers

**Is there any way to check if the TeamSpeak 3 client on the same computer is connected to a specific server? (same computer as the app that does this check)**

Yes, there is, one way of doing this is to get the server's `SID` (You can do that via the client plugin SDK), and if that matches the server's `SID`, then you are on the same server

**Alternatively, is there any way to check a TeamSpeak 3 server's client list that doesn't include using the steam query login credentials**

*First of all, I'm assuming you mean the server query, not steam query :p*

Anyways, yes, this is still achievable, however, in latter case, the problem is that the client list is only those which are visible (depends on the client's privilege).

**I know the steam query port, but not login credentials?**

The default setting, the only account a server has is `serveradmin`, and the password is the one you get when you first launch the server, or you can reset it by adding parameters `-serveradmin_password="new_password"` (go look up on TS Forum, they have it there), and the next possible way is to add a `serverquery` login when you connect to the TS3 server (but you need to have required permission to do so).